# How can i update multiple tables in SQL through inner joins?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables in SQL Reference, User and Details and i want to do the following.
Read the Value column in Table Reference , then link it to the assocaited rows in User table and from User link to the
Details Table and do an update.

```
Reference 
Id Name   Info   Value    Type

1  Name1  Deatils1  A     SE
2  Name2  Deatils2  B     SE
3  Name3  Deatils3  C     SE  
4  Name2  Deatils2  B     SA
5  Name3  Deatils3  C     SA 


User
UserId Type Membership  MemId    Org

1  Typea    Memberb     7
1  Typea    Memberb     7
1  Typea    Memberb     7
2  Typea    Memberb     8
2  Typea    Memberb     8
2  Typea    Memberb     8
2  Typea    Memberb     8
3  Typea    Memberb     9 
3  Typea    Memberb     9

Details
MemberId Vehicle     Expiry     Org

7        vehiclea    Expiry
7        vehiclea    Expiry
7        vehiclea    Expiry
7        vehiclea    Expiry
8        vehiclea    Expiry
8        vehiclea    Expiry
8        vehiclea    Expiry
8        vehiclea    Expiry
9        vehiclea    Expiry
9        vehiclea    Expiry
```

So for example
read first row in Reference table ie id =1 with Value A , then get all the rows in User table with UserId of 1 ,  then update
the Org column with the Value A and then get the  4 rows in Details linked by MemId and MemberId and update Org with that value as well
Then continue for the Id = 2 and Id =3 in the User table if and only if Type = 'SE'

The output would be something like

```
User
UserId Type Membership  MemId    Org

1  Typea    Memberb     7    A
1  Typea    Memberb     7    A
1  Typea    Memberb     7    A
2  Typea    Memberb     8    B
2  Typea    Memberb     8    B
2  Typea    Memberb     8    B
2  Typea    Memberb     8    B
3  Typea    Memberb     9    C
3  Typea    Memberb     9    C
                         
Details
MemberId Vehicle     Expiry     Org

7        vehiclea    Expiry     A 
7        vehiclea    Expiry     A
7        vehiclea    Expiry     A
7        vehiclea    Expiry     A
8        vehiclea    Expiry     B
8        vehiclea    Expiry     B 
8        vehiclea    Expiry     B
8        vehiclea    Expiry     B
9        vehiclea    Expiry     C
9        vehiclea    Expiry     C
```

How do i start with this ?

Comment: Such data model is not a good option as you replicate the same information many times, which may lead to inconsistencies (or you absolutely have to manage parallel updates to all this tables in a single transaction from an application side). Or you'll end up with uncontrolled number of cascading updates when your model evolves and new dependent tables are added (with such cascading dependency also). You may get all the required information at the query time with simple join

Comment: Apart from the above please show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it.

Comment: Please mention the dbms name and version.

Comment: I agree with astentx that this is something you shouldn't do. Don't store values redundantly. This can lead to inconsistencies later. Another issue with your data model is a user table where there are multiple entries for the same user ID. Get your database normalized. Apart from that: If you want to update two tables, start a transaction, then update one table, then update the other table, then commit your updates.

Comment: Thorsten Kettner , I have taken your approach "update one table, then update the other table, then commit your updates"